# Curl says Certificate has expired (10) but expire date is in the future

Tags: ssl, curl, lets-encrypt

on our domain (upfit.de), the certificate expires on the 13th of december 2021 and the certificate is valid from the outside (checked on sslchecker, in the browser, etc...).
On the server that hosts this domain, when I `curl -vvI https://upfit.de`, I get the following message:

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=upfit.de
*  start date: Sep 14 02:32:37 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 13 02:32:36 2021 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify result: certificate has expired (10), continuing anyway.
```

You have to agree that the message is a bit odd, it states that the certificate expired, but its expire date is on the 13th of December.
Any idea?

Comment: That message is probably referring to an intermediate or other certificate higher in the chain.

Comment: they seem to be valid: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=upfit.de

Comment: Could the time on the machine that's running curl have been set ahead?

Comment: The time is the right one.

Comment: Well, somehow it must see a different certificate than the rest of the internet does. I think [IdenTrust-signed R3 expired today](https://blog.dnsimple.com/2021/09/letsencrypt-intermediate-expiration/).

Comment: sslshopper only gives a summary result, but https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=upfit.de shows there are _two_ cert paths -- one ending in the ISRG root which is valid (if you have an up to date truststore), and one bridging to the DST root which as noted expired today; see better https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/ .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by updating the CA certificates curl uses.
I ran `sudo curl --insecure https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` (not very secure, but works).
This works for curl on command line.
For php_curl, I have to do something similar (apparently in `php.ini` with `curl.cainfo = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`).